# Printing the amount of digits to the right and left of a decimal place

Tags: java

I'm having trouble getting the number of digits to the left of the decimal place. I've got the digits to the right of the decimal point working and able to print out but not to the left. Can anyone help?

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class FormulaCalculation
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
  Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
  double x;

  //Prompt user for value.
  System.out.print("Enter a value for x: ");
  x = userInput.nextDouble();


  double result = (Math.sqrt(7 * Math.pow(x, 4) - 5 * Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.abs(98 * x)) + 13) * (3 * Math.pow(x, 5) + 4 * Math.pow(x, 3) + 1);
  String resultString = Double.toString(result);


  int integerPlaces = resultString.indexOf('.');
  int digitsLeft = resultString.length();
  int digitsRight = resultString.length() - integerPlaces - 1;


  //Output
  System.out.println("Result: " + result);
  System.out.println("# digits to left of the decimal point: " + digitsLeft);
  System.out.println("# digits to right of the decimal point: " + digitsRight);
  System.out.println("Formatted Result: ");
   }

}
```

Comment: *I've got the digits to the right of the decimal place working but not to the right* Which is it?

Comment: Fixed it. I meant I cannot get the amount of digits to the left to print out correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either print `integerPlaces` (which is the number you seek) or assign it to `digitsLeft`. Something like this,

```
int integerPlaces = resultString.indexOf('.');
int digitsLeft = integerPlaces; // <-- from 0 to the '.'
    // resultString.length();
int digitsRight = resultString.length() - integerPlaces - 1;
```

or eliminate `digitsLeft` altogether,

```
System.out.println("# digits to left of the decimal point: " + integerPlaces);
```